# HTTP request url is getting concatenated to other links

Tags: jquery, asp.net, http

I have an ascx control for a top menu on my page, on this I have some lists for different links on the site like:

```
<ul>
    <li class="catheading">Section select</li>
    <li><a href="/section1/subsection1">ONE</a></li>
    <li><a href="/section2/subsection2">TWO</a></li>
</ul>
```

This menu is animated by jquery. The thing is that lately we have an intermitent issue where the request logged on IIS logs are like:

/section1/section2/subsection2

and the only valid request should be:

/section1/subsection1

/section2/subsection2

Does anyone knows what may be the cause for this malformed request? As far as I know it should be on client side but have not found any information on this(BTW I'm using Chrome 43.0.2357.134 m). Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Perhaps users are just editing the URL by hand?

Comment: It was the first thing we though about... but someone from the company was able to reproduce it without any manipulation.

Comment: Well, then the obvious path is to write down how to reproduce the error, then log the path the request takes through your code.

Comment: Yes I have done that, the steps were as simple as clicking ramdomly the links. It is an intermitent issue so I have been not able to reproduce it. The site has log for requested paths and we have IIS logs as well, but all we get is the bad url's so that's why I was pointing to a browser side issue but wanted to ask if anyone knows of any reason why we can have this kind of scenario. Thank you!

Comment: The problem is likely that you're performing some redirects and you got the relative path wrong. Could be on the server or client, which is why you need to reproduce and watch the path through the code to identify which code is doing it improperly.